# Не могу получить св-во в GUI элементе в ассинхронном методе С#

Tags: c#

У меня есть ассинхронный метод. Вот его начинка:

```
foreach (var item in items)
             {

                  for (int j = 0; j <  listView1.Items.Count; j++)
                 {

                     if (listView1.Items[j].Checked == true)
                         //(listView1.Items[j].Checked == true)
                        {
                         if (listView1.Items[j].ToString().Contains(items.Tit) && listView1.Items[j].ToString().Contains(items.Art))
                         {
                             try
                             {
                                 i += 1;     
                                 MyMethod(params);
                                 //MessageBox.Show("Было выполнено -> " + listView1.Items[j]);
                                 label7.Invoke(new Action(() => { label7.Text = i.ToString(); }));
                                 }

                             catch(Exception t)
                             {
                                    i -= 1;     
                                    //MessageBox.Show("Не могу Выполнить");
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         continue;
                     }
                 }
            label3.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
            label3.Text = "Готов";
```

Всё это дело завёрнуто в такую конструкцию:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
          {
//тут весь код выше});
```

Получаю эксепшен на первом операторе IF: Cross-Threading operation.
По сути шерстится listView1 на предмет "чекнутых" элементов в нём. И есть следующий элемент чекнут, то переходим ко второму условию. Но программа "падает". Я пробовал сделать так:

```
if(listView1.Invoke(new Action(() => { listView1.Items[j].Checked == true })));
```

Тоже ошибка, тип так нельзя. Как можно по-простому поправить код, чтобы всё работало? Мне просто нужно достать свойство Checked у элемента.

Про второе условие не знаю, там идёт поиск подстроки, будет ли ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Асинхронный вызов метода подразумевает, что вы выполняете его не в UI потоке (в общем случае). Поэтому вам придётся на всех UI элементах (label, listView и т.п.) делать Invoke, чтобы доступ к элементам UI шёл в UI потоке.
Лучше вообще так не делать и выполнять метод, активно работающий с UI, целиком в UI потоке.

Comment: Так-то да, вот только foreach у меня может работать и 2 и 6 часов... Форма блокируется. Поэтому я и ищу способ взаимодействия.

Comment: @ANTARES Во время работы foreach интерфейс должен только прогресс отображать или ещё и принимать какой-то ввод? Если только отображать, то сделайте функцию Progress, вызывайте её периодически из цикла и делайте там Invoke все нужные, так будет понятнее. А то, что вы берёте из listView лучше соберите заранее и передайте в функцию в виде какой-то структуры данных. Это явно нехорошо, когда элементы UI опрашиваются в цикле, это сильно замедляет ваш код.

Comment: Кстати, я вообще не увидел, где вы используете переменную item, которая присваивается в цикле. У вас там везде items используется. Что-то тут неправильно.

Comment: Я просто убрал лишнее. Этот items содержит в себе кучу свойств. Пользуюсь я буквально 4-мя. Вообще сам foreach собирает необходимую инфу о файле из веба а mymethod выполняет загрузку. Я вот просто хотел выводить ход этой загрузки. Например, просто число вывести. Сами элементы списка listview имеют определенное название. И их то и должен проверять IF. Отмечены ли они и соответствуют ли они свойствам items. Я вот думал, возможно ли элементы listview просто выгрузить в Dictionary<bool, string>. Чтобы получилось bool (отмечено/ не отмечено) и string (само название из listview).

Comment: Я ппосто, мягко сказать, плыву с классами... И боюсь, что не достучусь до свойств items из другого метода. Я хотел сначала все перенести в массив, затем заполнить listview, а потом уже все остальное. Но я что-то не понял/ не нашёл как заполнить массив объектами. И чтобы не было null reference exception. Поэтому я пошел не хорошим путём, как показано выше.

Comment: @ANTARES И всё же проверьте, у вас там странное, что цикл по items и при этом на каждом шаге цикла эти же items используются, а не переменная item, в которой элементы items перебираются. То ли вы вообще делаете?
И да, лучше заранее создать какие-то объекты, в которые скопировать свойства из всех listview и обращаться уже к этим объектам в функции, которая долго работает.